# MSBuild on Centos returns "The imported project "/Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found"

Tags: linux, msbuild, centos, dotnet-sdk

I'm trying to build a VS project in CentOS. I installed dotnet-sdk-2.2 via `yum install dotnet-sdk-2.2`.

When executing `dotnet msbuild myproj.vcxproj` I get:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.1.76+g14b0a930a7 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

mtproj.vcxproj(19,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"
was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the
file exists on disk.
```

Googling results with many solutions but for Windows. what can I do to resolve this over Linux/CentOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your error message it's a C++ project.

Please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild),the dotnet CLI only supports .NET / .NET Core / .NET Standard projects.

C++ projects are part of the visual studio tooling (c++ workload). The dotnet CLI doesn't contain the visual c++ compiler or the necessary windows SDKs. So it's not supported to build C++ projects directly using dotnet msbuild in Windows, not to speak of CentOS.

To build C++ projects in linux, you can try [g++ compiler](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html), you can find many related info about how to use it online.

Also, maybe you can try using [GCCBuild](https://github.com/roozbehid/dotnet-vcxproj) to build vcxproj files in Linux. It simple uses same structure of vcxproj but uses GCC to compile and build. Thanks to Roozbeh.