# Is it possible to manage with Azure Pipeline net core projects with dependencies on c++ projects?

Tags: c#, c++, azure-devops

I've tried to compile c++ projects with VSBuild@1 or with CMake@1 but when I try to publish or test net core projects, I' ve got many problems. here part of the pipeline

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build projects cpp'
  inputs:
    projects: '$src/**/*.vcxproj'
    platform: 'x64'
    configuration: 'release'
    clean: true

- task: CMake@1
  displayName: 'CMake projects cpp'
  inputs:
    projects: '$src/**/*.vcxproj'
    platform: 'x64'
    configuration: 'release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build net project'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'src/**/*.csproj'
    arguments: "--configuration $(buildConfiguration)"
```

but with the last task I get the following error

```
2020-05-19T15:41:53.5561920Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Core
2020-05-19T15:41:53.5562860Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2020-05-19T15:41:53.5563181Z 
2020-05-19T15:42:03.7907177Z   Restore completed in 1.06 sec for d:\a\1\s\src\TetraPak.DPP.InferenceTemplate\TetraPak.DPP.InferenceTemplate.csproj.
2020-05-19T15:42:03.7908355Z   Restore completed in 1.06 sec for d:\a\1\s\src\TetraPak.DPP.InferenceTemplate.Tests\TetraPak.DPP.InferenceTemplate.Tests.csproj.
2020-05-19T15:42:04.3458345Z ##[error]src\InferenceCppMixed\InferenceCppMixed.vcxproj(21,3): Error MSB4019: The imported project "d:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
2020-05-19T15:42:04.3482114Z d:\a\1\s\src\InferenceCppMixed\InferenceCppMixed.vcxproj(21,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "d:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
2020-05-19T15:42:05.1672338Z ##[error]src\InferenceCppMixed\InferenceCppMixed.vcxproj(21,3): Error MSB4019: The imported project "d:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
2020-05-19T15:42:05.1686580Z d:\a\1\s\src\InferenceCppMixed\InferenceCppMixed.vcxproj(21,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "d:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
2020-05-19T15:42:05.6046350Z 
2020-05-19T15:42:05.6047687Z Build FAILED.
2020-05-19T15:42:05.6048625Z
```

Comment: Can you be specific on what kind of problems you are experiencing? That would help in diagnosing and crafting answers.

Comment: Of course ... when I compile projects in C++ it works, when I compile locally the .net core project it works. If I try to compile on Devops .net project, the error you see for c++ projects appear (the net core project has a c++ project in the reference)
This is because C++ projects have inside project file: 
<Import Project = "$ (VCTargetsPath) \ Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
and other Microsoft imports...

Comment: Hi friend, If below answer resolved your question, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to manage with Azure Pipeline net core projects with
>   dependencies on c++ projects?

The answer is **Yes**. However it's recommended to use `Msbuild task` or `VS build task` instead of `DotnetCore task` to build your .net core project in this specific scenario. (Add a nuget restore/dotnet restore task before building .net core project)

Normally `dotnet build` is good choice to build `.net core/.net standard` projects. But since your project references one C++ project, `dotnet build` will also try to build the C++ project. Meanwhile `$(VCTargetsPath)` is one unique C++ property which is not recognized by dotnet CLI (Check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56553726/10910450)). That's the reason why the issue occurs...

More Details:

1.It's not `when I compile projects in C++ it works, when I compile locally the .net core project it works. If I try to compile on Devops .net project, the error you see for c++ projects appear`.

It's `when building those project locally in VS, it works`. When building in VS, it always calls msbuild(which supports C++ and .net) to build .net core projects. VS is not calling dotnet build(which doesn't support C++) to build .net core projects. We can easily reproduce same issue and confirm this by calling dotnet build command in CMD:

[image]

2.You can feel free to use VSBuild/MSBuild task to build your .net core project. And you may need to add a dotnet restore task before building .net core project to restore the nuget packages for .net core project:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
```

Comment: @user2273396 Hi friend, do you mind [accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442) so that other members can easily find the marked answer. And then we can archive this issue for you. Thanks :)

Comment: Accepted ... I've been consulting stackoverflow for a lifetime, but I never tried to ask questions. Thanks again